# how to change a list of tuples into individual lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

i have the following lists which consists of tuples , every tuple has items related together
the items in every tuple represents an animal , his speed and his weight respictivly

```
tuples_list=[(cat,250,50),(lion,650,400),(tiger,700,450)]
```

firstly i wanted to arrange the tuple_list in a descinding manner according to the second item in the tuples
so i used the following

```
def sorted_tuple(tuples_list):
    return(sorted(tuple_lists, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))#to sort the tuples inside the list from highest to lowest speed
```

so the tuples_list became:

```
tuples_list=[(tiger,700,450),(lion,650,400),(cat,250,50)]
```

now i need to do the following
separate the animals into a list , their speed into a second list and their weight into a third list
so i did the following

```
animal=[]
speed=[]
weight=[]
animal,speed,weight=zip(*sorted_tuple(tuples_list))
```

so i expected the following result

```
animal=[tiger,lion,cat]
speed= [700,  650, 250]
weight=[450,  400,  50]
```

so every animal has his speed and weight directly below him in the other lists
but when i tried to change an item in the speed list into another value under certain condition

```
lets say speed[0]=speed[0]+50
```

i got the following error

```
'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

so where is the problem exactly please correct me
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use zip function, if preferences are fixed then you can directly iterate within that list, Here it is,

```
tuples_list=[('tiger',700,450),('lion',650,400),('cat',250,50)]

animal = [i[0] for i in tuples_list]
speed = [i[1] for i in tuples_list]
weight= [i[2] for i in tuples_list]

speed[0]=speed[0]+50
```

output

```
['tiger', 'lion', 'cat']
[750, 650, 250]
[450, 400, 50]
```

Comment: Can you tell me what was the problem in my code in details please, thank you

Comment: name of tupple list  is `tuples_list` but in sorted_tuple function you have written `tuple_lists`  which raises `NameError: name 'tuple_lists' is not defined` error

Comment: second when you call sorted_function it gives you tuple itself not list and as we all know tuple is immutable. hence it is not allowed to do `speed[0]=speed[0]+50` this

Answer (score 1):

*OP: where is the problem exactly please correct me*

When you tried to convert the list of tuples into list of list using:

```
animal,speed,weight=zip(*sorted_tuple(tuples_list))
```

it did not create list of list rather only tuples i.e.:

```
speed= (700,  650, 250)
```

You can still add the speed in the tuple using:

```
speed[0]+50
```

But you cannot change their value since `tuples in Python are immutable`, so you cannot do this:

```
speed[0]=speed[0]+50
```

Use the index on sorted list of tuples and then assign the animal, speed and weight:

```
def sorted_tuple(tuples_list):
    return(sorted(tuples_list, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

tuples_list=[('tiger',700,450),('lion',650,400),('cat',250,50)]    
temp_lst = sorted_tuple(tuples_list)

animal = [x[0] for x in temp_lst]
speed =  [x[1] for x in temp_lst]
weight = [x[2] for x in temp_lst]

print(speed[0]+ 50)
```

**EDIT**:

You could also achieve the same using `zip()` with indexing:

```
animal  = list(list(zip(*temp_lst))[0])
speed = list(list(zip(*temp_lst))[1])
weight = list(list(zip(*temp_lst))[2])
print(speed[0]+ 50)
```